# warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] even if with "return 0;" in main function

Tags: c, pointers

I have some code here that raises a warning

> **control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]**.

What makes me confused is that, if I add `return 0;` in function printer, the warning will disappear. I am a freshman to the language C, so hopefully you can help me solve this problem. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int printer(int *ip){
    printf("%d", *ip);
//  return 0; //with the expression, the warning will disappear. why?
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int number = 10;
    int *ip;
    ip = &number;

    printer(ip);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, what did you declare the `printer` function to return and what did you actually return?

Comment: or Change return type of `printer` to `void` from `int`.

Comment: It's not magic. Whatever you declare your function return `type` to be, you should return a value of that `type`, e.g. `void foo() { ..returns nothing, but can return;.. }`; `int foo() { .. returns an int;.. }`; `char *foo() { ..returns a char*;.. }` -- you get the drift.

Comment: thanks all of you for responding. now I know that it raise a warning rather than an error, just because the return value of printer has not been used.

Answer (score 3):

You declare the printer function to return an integer.

```
int printer(...
```

but you don't return an integer.
I think you need to make it

```
void printer(...
```

in order for it to work without the return statement in the function

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is printing the warning for `printer()` because it cannot assume that the function will never be called from other functions than `main()` and its return value is accidentally used.

To solve this problem, you have to give up writing such dangerous code: return some value via `return` statement or declare type of return value as `void`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int printer(int *ip){
    printf("%d", *ip);
//  return 0; //with the expression, the warning will disappear. why?
}
```

This function returns a value of type `int`, as it is specified in the header of it:

```
int printer(int *ip)
```

The `int` at the start of the statement means that this function is supposed to return a value to the function that is calling it. This means that the calling function expects a value from `printer()`.

If you have a void return value, then the calling function will not expect a return value, hence doing something like this:

```
 int num = AnyFunction();
```

Where `AnyFunction()` is an example function that returns `void`, or nothing, will cause an error. However, if `AnyFunction()` returns an `int` value, then the above statement works, which is your case. Now, if your function does not return anything, even though it should, then what value will be stored in `num`?

Therefore, the compiler gives you a warning, because you may not use the return value by `printer()` function in your code, and therefore do not require a return statement. However, if you try to use a statement like something above, then your `printer()` function will not return anything, which will cause problems. In your case, you do not use the return value of `printer()`, so your code will not run into problems.

---

To remove the error, either you can do:

```
return 0; // You did this, and you noticed that this resolved the issue
```

This eliminates the issue as you return a value 0 (we use 0 by convention, correct me please if I am wrong on this) just for namesake. The return value, like I said, is not used at all, therefore, the warning is resolved.

Alternatively, you can also change your function header to:

```
void printer(int *ip) {
```

This eliminates the warning, as now, your function returns a value of type `void`, which is nothing. In your case, this is better as you do not use the value 0 returned by the statement in the first choice.